# Serious issue when iterating through lists in Java [indexOutOfBounds]

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing code to make a program that applies many principles of computational linguistics. My problem at this moment is the following piece of code form a method that "flexibilizes two definitions".
This is, it compares two different definitions of the same word, and in each definition empty or blank spaces will be added to later on work with the altered definitions (with blank spaces added).
Say we have the following two definitions, defining the term "free fall".

```
1) Free fall descent  of a body subjected only to            the   action of  gravity.
2) Free fall movement of a body in        a    gravitational field under  the influence of gravity
```

There is a list of words called stoplist, which contains the words: "of", "a", "in", "to", and "under". After the process, each word in the definition that is also contained in the stoplist must correspond to a blank space OR another stoplist word of the other definition.
So after executing such process, the previous definitions, represented in two different lists, should look like this:

```
1) Free fall descent  of a body ____ ____ subjected     only  to     the action    of gravity.
2) Free fall movement of a body in   a    gravitational field under  the influence of gravity.
```

The code I wrote to achieve this is the following:

---

```
[...]
    String[] sList = STOPLIST.split(" ");  //this is the stoplist
    String[] definition1 = defA1.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the first definition
    String[] definition2 = defA2.split(" ");  //this is the array of words of the second definition
    List<String> def1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
    List<String> def2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> stopList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String word : definition1){
         def1.add(word); //I transform arrays into lists this way because I used to think that using .asList() was the problem.
    }
    for(String word : definition2){
         def2.add(word);
    }
    for(String word : sList){
        stopList.add(word);
    }

    int mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(); //here mdef will have the value of the lenght of the shortest definition, and we are going to use the value of mdef to iterate later on.

    for(int i = 0; i < mdef; i++){
        if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {  //here I check if the first word of the first definition is also found in the stoplist.
            if (!stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {  //If the word of def1 previously checked is in the stoplist, as well as the corresponding word in the second definition, then we won't add a " "(blank) space in the corresponding position of the second definition.
                def2.add(i , " "); //here I add that blank space, only if the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a non-stoplist word in def2. Again, we do this so the stoplist word in def1 corresponds to a blank space OR another stoplist word in def2.
                if(mdef == def2.size())
                    mdef++; //In case the shortest definition is the definition to which we just added spaces, we increment mdef++, because that space added increases the length of the shortest definition, and to iterate in this recenlty extended definiton, we have to increment the index with which we iterate.
            }
        } else if (stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) { //this else if does the same than the previous one, but checks for the second definition instead of the first one. And adds blanks to def1 instead of def2 if necessary.
            if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {
                def1.add(i , " ");
                if(mdef == def1.size())
                    mdef++;
            }
        }
    }
[...]
```

---

Now, if you analyze the code carefully, you will realize that not all words of the lengthiest list will be checked, given that we iterate ove the definitions using the lenght of the shortest definition as index. This is fine, the remainding words of the lenghtiest definitions don't have to be checked, they will correspond to null spaces of the other definition (in case the lists don't end up being of the same lenght after the addition of spaces, as the previous exaple shows).

Now, after the explanation, the problem is the following: after running the main class, which calls the method that contains the previous code, a runtime exceptions pops out:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
        at main2.main(main2.java:75)
```

I don't understand why it is finding any of the lists as "empty".
I have tried to solve it in too many ways, I hope a I gave a good explanation.

It may help as a clue that if I assign mdef to the lengthiest size instead of the shortest, that is :

```
    int mdef = (def1.size() >= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size();
```

the error changes to:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 15
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at asmethods.lcc.turnIntoFlex(lcc.java:55)
    at asmethods.lcc.calLcc(lcc.java:99)
    at main2.main(main2.java:73)'
```

Where lcc is the class that contains the method turnIntoFlex that contains the piece of code I'm showing. The line 55 of "turnIntoFlex" corresponds to the first line of the loop, that is:

```
    if (stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) { [...]
```

Comment: Which line is line 75?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the mdef++ that is increasing the range of the loop, causing the index to be out of bounds for the shorter list

Comment: Instead of mdef = (def1.size() <= def2.size()) ? def1.size() : def2.size(), you can use the easier Math.min(def1.size(), def2.size());

Comment: Whichever line is line 75, it is trying to retrieve index 1 from a 0-sized (i.e. empty) array.

Comment: What are the values of `defA1` and `defA2`? Can you confirm that `def1` and `def2` are being populated (i.e., print out their contents)?

Comment: `Serious issue when iterating through lists in Java` - solution: `C#`.

Comment: did you actually debug it?? this seems easy to find with debugger.

Comment: Hi, the values of defA1 and defA2 are the definitions, respectively. i.e. def1 and def2, initially, are lists in which each separate element is a word. I can't check if these lists are being populated by printing them because the indexoutofboundsexception pops at the very moment the loop starts. However, I do print the values of the sizes of mdef, def1.size() and def2.size(), and the values turn out to be 13, or 15, showing that no list is empty before the "for" loop starts.

Comment: To everyone, line 75 is in the main method, where I call the method of another class where this piece of code is contained.   
The other two lines the compiler points out are in the API. These two lines are at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)

Comment: Also, @Evans, the mdef++ was something I added recently, not to exactly to solve this specific problem, but the error has been popping since before I added the mdef++ part. As I explained, The intention is to increase mdef++ when the shortest list is extended (but only when the short list is extended) so we iterate through all the words of the short list, and not more.

Comment: I edited the question to add some additional information that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    else if (stopList.contains(def2.get(i))) {
        if (!stopList.contains(def1.get(i))) {
            def1.add(i , " ");
            if(mdef == def2.size())
                mdef++;
        }
    }
```

Should the if statement mdef == def2.size() not be mdef == def1.size() ?  You just added to def1

Comment: Yes Taylor you're right. The real code is right as well don't worry.